# Trigger.Once Spark Structured Streaming with KAFKA possible?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

Does Spark Structured Streaming using Trigger.Once allow for a direct connection to KAFKA and use of MERGE statement? Or must the data for this be from a delta table?

This https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/merge-in-scd-type-2.html assumes tables as input. I cannot find an example with KAFKA being used with Trigger.Once. OK, the weekend is coming and I will fire up this and that, but it is an interesting point that I would like to know in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use `Trigger.Once` (or better newer `Trigger.AvailableNow`) with Kafka, and then use `foreachBatch` to execute MERGE.

The only thing that you need to take into account is that data shouldn't expire between executions.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.

Comment: The last comment you mean? I am not sure I follow.

Comment: I wanted to say that next trigger should happen before data expire in Kafka. Like, we have expiration of 7 days by default, so you need to run pipeline every 6 days or something

Comment: Gotcha. No issue here. Thx